# How do I access a globally defined typedef struct through pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I want to know how to use a typedef struct outside the file where it is located. I mean, I have this:

In a File called "rtc_i2c.c" I have ------------------------------------

```
#include "rtc_i2c.h"

struct time_date_str
{
  char year;
  char month;
  char date;
  char day;

  char hour;
  char minute;
  char second;
};


int RTCGetTime(TimeDate *timdatstrptr)
{
  timdatstrptr -> second = 0x12;

  return 0;
}
```

Then in a file called "rtc_i2c.h" I have -------------------------------

```
#ifndef RTC_I2C_H 
#define RTC_I2C_H 

typedef struct time_date_str TimeDate;

#endif
```

And in "main.c" I have -------------------------------------------------

```
#include "rtc_i2c.h"

TimeBase *TimeDateData;

void main(void)
{
  char DateTimeASCII[20]; 

  RTCGetTime(TimeDateData);

  DateTimeASCII[0] = ????????
}
```

Then when I step in to my code I enter in to RTCGetTime and in a watch window I can see the "timdatstrptr -> second = 12" assignment executing correctly. But the problem is outside. The compiler generates an error if I put "TimeDateData --> second" in the space with ????????. So I don't know how am I supposed to access the contents of my globally defined array through a pointer.

If I understood, the pointer declared as "TimeBase *TimeDateData" is pointing to my array and is accessed with the "-->" because is a pointer. Am I wrong? how does this work?

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the details of the `time_date_str`. You have 2 choices:

- Move the `struct time_date_str` declaration into the header file
- Make a sort of "accessor" function in `rtc_i2c.c`

It all boils down to the question: should outside entities know details about this structure ?

There are other problems as well, including the fact that you're passing an uninitialized pointer to `RTCGetTime`.

Comment: @cnincutalyes all the outside entities should have access to this structure. I already moved the struct to the .h file but still failing to compile. The error is "undeclared identifier" if I put "DateTimeASCII[0] = TimeDateData --> second;"

Comment: @user1502121 Try using a normal variable, `TimeBase TimeDateData` which you can pass like so: `RTCGetTime(&TimeDateData)`.

Comment: @cnincutalyes thanks! that solved it. I changed "TimeBase *TimeDateData" for "TimeBase TimeDateData" and passed like "&TimeDateData" and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use that struct outside the file where it is located, that's why it is located in a file `rtc_i2c.c`, and not in `rtc_i2c.h`. Try to find other ways to accomplish what you need.

For example, i guess a declaration of `RTCGetTime` also appears somewhere in `rtc_i2c.h`, that's why you can use it in another file (`main.c`). So, look for other useful functions in `rtc_i2c.h`, maybe there is something that you can use?

If you absolutely cannot proceed this way, just move the definition of the struct to the header file:

```
#ifndef RTC_I2C_H 
#define RTC_I2C_H 

struct time_date_str
{
  char year;
  char month;
  char date;
  char day;

  char hour;
  char minute;
  char second;
};

typedef struct time_date_str TimeDate;

#endif
```